# How would I recompile Ripper's AST back to Ruby code?

Tags: ruby, abstract-syntax-tree, ruby-ripper

Ripper is the the parsing library that ships with Ruby 1.9.  It transforms Ruby code into an AST, like so:

```
pp Ripper.sexp("def foo; yield :a; return 1 end")

#=>

[:program,
 [[:def,
   [:@ident, "foo", [1, 4]],
   [:params, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil],
   [:bodystmt,
    [[:yield,
      [:args_add_block,
       [[:symbol_literal, [:symbol, [:@ident, "a", [1, 16]]]]],
       false]],
     [:return, [:args_add_block, [[:@int, "1", [1, 26]]], false]]],
    nil,
    nil,
    nil]]]]
```

**Is there a library to take this AST and transform it back into Ruby code?**

[ruby_parser and ruby2ruby](http://seattlerb.rubyforge.org/ruby2ruby/) used to do this, but I would like to use Ripper as my parser.  (Ruby 1.9 may even ship with such a library, but I'm struggling to find documentation even on Ripper itself)

Comment: I played around with https://github.com/svenfuchs/ripper2ruby given http://www.artweb-design.de/2009/7/5/ripper2ruby-modify-and-recompile-your-ruby-code, but it died with NoMethodError: undefined method `to_ruby' for #<Ruby::Node::Composite::Array:0x9aa7540>. Not sure where to go from there.

Comment: I found that at some point, but it just didn't seem reliable.  Thanks for offering up your experience with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See "[Sorcerer](https://github.com/jimweirich/sorcerer)". This works well but I found a bug when parsing methods. If you add `src.emit("; ")` below the line 301 of the file "lib/sorcerer/resource.rb", this will be fixed. But you may find more if you decide to use this. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks - this looks like the best thing out there at the moment!

Comment: up to date version is here https://github.com/rspec-given/sorcerer